# Why would the tab "WCF Options" not be in Visual Studio 2008 project properties?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf

On one machine with **VS2008** installed, when I right-click on a **WCF service library project** and choose properties, I don't have the "**WCF Options**" tab but on **three** other computers the tab is there. The project is all the same one, from TFS.

The only difference is that the one that doesn't have the tab is **Vista** and the others are all **XP**.

All machines have VS2008 SP1 and I **reinstalled SP1** on the Vista machine but no difference.

**Could this be a rights problem at some level, or what else could be causing the VS2008 not to have this "WCF Options" tag on the project properties?**

### Additional Info:

- Even when I create a new WCF Service
  Library **from scratch**, there is no
  "WCF Options" tab.
- Even when I create
  a new WCF Service Library **with
  Visual Web Developer 2008 Express**
  there is no "WCF Options" tab.

[image]

Comment: Probably, you'll need to install the SP1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new WCF service library project and inspect its .csproj, is there a section like below?

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}">
        <WcfProjectProperties>
          <AutoStart>True</AutoStart>
        </WcfProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

If not, what happens when you add it yourself?

Comment: interesting: no, I don't have that XML block when I created a new WCF service library project, I added the above block right under the <Project...> tag in my .csproj but it didn't show me the tag in VisualStudio project properties. I tried this on one of the machines that DOES have the tag and it DOES have that XML block.

Comment: I don't have a Vista machine here with Visual Studio 2008 so I can't verify whether it's an installation problem or a Vista problem. Do you have access to a second Vista machine?
Did your Visual Studio 2005 installation on Vista have the WCF Extensions installed?

Comment: Update: on my home Vista box, I don't have the tab either!
And it's a fresh VS2008 install, no VS2005 was ever on this machine..

Comment: @Michel are you sure you have VS2008 SP1? The WCF-Options apparently comes with SP1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391658.aspx

Comment: MS Visual Studio 2008 version 9.0.21022.8 RTM 
.Net Framework 3.5 SP1
(RTM because that's the version I got with the webdeveloper dvd that comes with Microsoft Action Pack)

Comment: I just deinstalled VS2008, VS2005, Visual Web Developer Express, and Blend (in case there were some conflicts), then reinstalled VS2005, and the VS2008 update, after a fresh install it says my Visual Studio is "Version 9.0.30729.1 SP" which is what it says on the other XP machines which have the WCF Options. Strange: under project templates it only has three Silverlight project templates and nothing else (no WPF, no WCF, no Console application, etc.)

Comment: then I installed Windows SP1 for Visual Studio 2008 which now has all the project templates including WCF, and when I create a WCF project it indeed does have the WCF-Options tab! So, the answer to this question seems to be: deinstall / reinstall. Thanks for your help, Michel!

Comment: For my project there is a section like that, but I still don't see the WCF options tab.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade from visual studio 2008 beta?
I would remove it completely and reinstall.

Can you try the following:

Close all VS instances and open a command prompt and run
`"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\vsdiag_regwcf.exe" -s`

If it doesn't state 'Registered", run:
`"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\vsdiag_regwcf.exe" -i`

Open your project and check for the missing tab.

Regards,
Michel

Comment: I upgraded from Visual Studio 2005, not from 2008beta. When I run the first command, it says "Registered...C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config" so it seems to be registered. I ran the second command as well, and checked, but the WCF-Options tab is still not there.

Comment: Hmm ok.  
Maybe and if you reset your development settings?

Tools->Import and Export Settings, Reset Settings.  
Close VS, Open VS.

Comment: I reset settings, restarted Visual Studio, but it still doesn't show a WCF-Options tag.

Comment: All the statuses are registered but still no WCF options window